# Why does it help to assign a const& scalar value to a const before a loop?

Tags: c++, gcc, temporary, stl-algorithm, gcc5

In GCC 5.4.0's `stl_algobase.h` we have:

```
  template<typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Tp>
    inline typename
    __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<!__is_scalar<_Tp>::__value, void>::__type
    __fill_a(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last,
         const _Tp& __value)
    {
      for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
    *__first = __value;
    }

  template<typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Tp>
    inline typename
    __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<__is_scalar<_Tp>::__value, void>::__type
    __fill_a(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last,
         const _Tp& __value)
    {
      const _Tp __tmp = __value;
      for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
    *__first = __tmp;
    }
```

I don't understand why the variant for scalars has any advantage over the general variant. I mean, won't they be compiled into exactly the same thing? Loading the `__value` from the stack into a register and  using that register throughout the loop?

Comment: It may be a trade-off between locality and making a potentially expensive copy, which could also have side-effects.

Comment: @juanchopanza: But for scalars, there is not expensive copy. Isn't it a given that any marginally-optimizing compiler would put the scalar in a register, even with the first version of the code?

Comment: So for scalars a copy is explicitly made. The locality probably makes the optimizer's job easier.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I thought the compiler is smart enough to do a same job for scalars. Isn't it?

Comment: @deepmax I don't know, is it?

Comment: One potential issue is aliasing.  The compiler may have a harder time determining whether it is safe to keep the value in a register since the value could potentially be overwritten during the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This originated in SVN rev 83645 (git commit 8ba26e53) in 2004, when both `__fill_a` variants where implemented as helper structs:

```
template<typename>
struct __fill
{
  template<typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Tp>
    static void
    fill(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last,
     const _Tp& __value)
    {
  for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
    *__first = __value;
}
};

template<>
struct __fill<__true_type>
{
  template<typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Tp>
    static void
    fill(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last,
     const _Tp& __value)
    {
  const _Tp __tmp = __value;
  for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
    *__first = __tmp;
}
};
```

Documentation on this topic is sparse, but the original commit by  Dan Nicolaescu and Paolo Carlini contains a hint in the commit message:

> - include/bits/stl_algobase.h (__fill, __fill_n): New helpers
>     for fill and fill_n, respectively: ***when copying is cheap, use a
>     temporary to avoid a memory read in each iteration.***

Given that those are/were maintainers of the standard library, I think they knew what there are doing: they tackle the problem that **references are usually implemented as pointers**. After all, they are just a new alias to an already existing memory location. That's why there were two variants originally. Note that the `__true_type` was decided in the `fill` call:

```
  typedef typename __type_traits<_Tp>::has_trivial_copy_constructor
    _Trivial;
  std::__fill<_Trivial>::fill(__first, __last, __value);
```

With `std::enable_if`, or rather its GCC variant, Carlini removed those helpers and replaced them by the version you've already provided. The logic still holds: for scalar types, you want to have some local value. If your range is in another memory region than your value and spans several pages and spills your L1 cache, you don't want to keep a bit of your cache locked down for that value. And it's trivial with a local variable.

However, the semantics are important. `std::fill` generates exactly `std::distance(first, last)` copies. With scalar values, we know that an additional copy won't have a side-effect. With user defined types? Well, we don't know. And that's why you cannot use the `const auto tmp = __value;` variant in the first case.

And that's why you end up with two, well, actually three variants:

- one for scalar values were you can keep the value "close" and help the optimizer
- one for byte-like values, where you can use memset
- one for all the other types, where you cannot meddle with the semantics.

Comment: If suse.de was still a valid domain, I would send Carlini an email, though.